# I am trying to make a plot as given below. Can anyone help me with this? I use below code to get one but doesn't work

Tags: plotting

[image: I am trying to get this kind of plot]

```
ListContourPlot3D[{{{0.63523489`, 0.75456796`, 0.94901556`, 
    1.10996668`}, {0.65912289`, 0.78212427`, 0.98253842`, 
    1.14847274`}, {0.68456582`, 0.81155279`, 1.01846831`, 
    1.18984549`}, {0.69805395`, 0.82720578`, 1.03766503`, 
    1.21201753`}}, {{0.7473693`, 0.88301594`, 1.10377358`, 
    1.28631074`}, {0.77610795`, 0.91655684`, 1.1452191`, 
    1.33441098`}, {0.80671229`, 0.95237171`, 1.18963473`, 
    1.38608436`}, {0.82293333`, 0.97141841`, 1.21336143`, 
    1.41377146`}}, {{0.9888752`, 1.15950616`, 1.43675863`, 
    1.66569301`}, {1.02797118`, 1.20580765`, 1.49507241`, 
    1.73420398`}, {1.06959265`, 1.25523425`, 1.55754627`, 
    1.80777897`}, {1.09164471`, 1.28151053`, 1.59090716`, 
    1.84718443`}}, {{1.23819456`, 1.444823`, 1.78024993`, 
    2.05698779`}, {1.28791742`, 1.5042035`, 1.85583346`, 
    2.14638205`}, {1.34083997`, 1.56757739`, 1.93678881`, 
    2.2423569`}, {1.36887152`, 1.60125878`, 1.98000534`, 
    2.2937414`}}}, 
DataRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 1.075`}, {-1.075`, 1.075`}}, 
PlotLegends -> Rainbow, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

> The x axis range are [0. , 1.5, 3. , 4.5, 6. ]  y axis range are [0. ,
> 0.26875, 0.5375 , 0.80625, 1.075 ]  z axis range are [-1.075 , -0.5375, 0. , 0.5375, 1.075 ]  The first value i.e. 0.63523489 is the distribution values that exists in x-axis range of 0 to 1.5, y-axis
> range of 0 to 0.26875 and z-axis range of -1.075 to -0.5375 and so on
> for other distribution values. So, it's like the three dimensional box
> with 64 small boxes where each box has given distribution values. As I
> said, one box has distribution value of 0.63523489.

Comment: Works with MMA version 13.0.1. But use "PlotLegends -> Automatic"  because "PlotLegends -> Rainbow" is wrong.

Comment: @DanielHuber in `V13.0.0` I get [`this`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUdaJ.png)

Comment: @bmf yes, I got the same as yours! I want the one as in question given!

Comment: I get the same plot as @bmf has shown in v12.2.0 on Win7-x64. I think the question is yet unclear and the OP needs to provide additional context. What are the equations for the regions that are shown in different colors enclosing other regions?

Comment: to the author of the OP: please take into consideration the comment by @Syed

Comment: @Syed I went through that as well but when I provide my data to SmoothKernelDistribution as in the solution there, it says that it should be a vector or matrix

Comment: The x axis has range are  [0. , 1.5, 3. , 4.5, 6. ]
y axis range are [0.     , 0.26875, 0.5375 , 0.80625, 1.075  ]
z axis range are [-1.075 , -0.5375,  0.    ,  0.5375,  1.075 ]
The first value i.e. 0.63523489 is the distribution values that exists in x-axis range of 0 to 1.5, y-axis range of 0 to 0.26875 and z-axis range of -1.075 to -0.5375 and so on for other distribution values. So, it's like the three dimensional box with 64 small boxes where each box has given distribution values. As I said, one box has distriubiton value of 0.63523489.